# Is it considered good practice to store unit test inputs/expected outputs in a flat file?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm finding myself writing a lot of boilerplate for my unit tests. I could down on that boilerplate significantly if I stored my unit test inputs along with the expected outputs in a csv file and directed my test suite to read the inputs form that file, pass them to the function being tested, and then compare its output with the values in the file's expected output column.

Is this considered good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing this in a separate file, I would recommend to store it in some kind of table (probably an array) inside your test code and iterate over that table.  Most testing frameworks have specific support for this: in JUnit the feature is called *parameterized tests*.  Then you even don't have to implement the iteration over that set of inputs and expected outputs yourself.